# Inherit annotations from abstract class?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Can I somehow group a set of annotations on an abstract class, and every class that extends this class has automatically assigned these annotations?

At least the following does not work:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class AbstractService


class PersonService extends AbstractService {
    @Autowired //will not work due to missing qualifier annotation
    private PersonDao dao;
}
```

Comment: I think that `PersonService` still needs to be annotated as `@Service`. But methods keep their annotation even when overriden.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**The answer is: no**

Java annotations are not inherited unless the annotation type has the @Inherited meta-annotation on it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html.

Spring's `@Component` annotation [does not have @Inherited on it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html), so you will need to put the annotation on each component class. @Service, @Controller and @Repository neither.

Answer (score 16):

The short answer is: with the annotations that you mentioned in your example, **no**.

The long answer: there is a meta-annotation called `java.lang.annotation.Inherited`. If an annotation itself is annotated with this annotation, then when a class is annotated with it, its subclasses are also automatically annotated with it by implication.

However, as you can see in the spring source code, the `@Service` and `@Scope` annotation are not themselves annotated with `@Inherited`, so the presence of `@Service` and `@Scope` on a class is not inherited by its subclasses.

Maybe this is something that can be fixed in Spring.

Answer (score 2):

I have this piece of code in my project and it works just fine, although it's not annotated as Service:

```
public abstract class AbstractDataAccessService {

    @Autowired
    protected GenericDao genericDao;


}
```

and

```
@Component
public class ActorService extends AbstractDataAccessService {

    // you can use genericDao here

}
```

So you don't need to put annotation on your abstract class but even if you do you will still have to put annotation on all subclass as `@Component` or `@Service` annotations are not inherited.