# How to be sure that an overridden method is annotated as in the parent class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have the following structure:
**MyInterface**: defines a public void finalizeBean() method
**MyAbsctractClass**: Implements this method and annotates it with @Remove annotation
**MyChildClass**: does not override the finalizeBean method.

As far as I understood, if I call childClass.finalizeBean() method, because it is defined in the parent class (MyAbsctractClass), the default implementation will be called and the @Remove annotation will be considered.

If I create a second child class (say ChildClassTwo) and override the finalizeBean method, I will have to remember to annotate the method with the @Remove annotation.

Is there any way I can be sure that even if the child class overrides the finalizeBean method, that the @Remove annotation will be considered?

About the duplicate: this post is about annotations in the class itself. Do annotations on methods that are not override also works as explained in the referred answer?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409338/inherit-annotations-from-abstract-class

If you made the annotation yourself, you can add the @Inherited annotation to your Annotation (in the Annotation class itself), otherwise you have to see if the Annotation type you're using supports inheritance.

Comment: @D3_JMultiply I edited the question because the link you provided talk about class annotations. Do annotations on methods that are not override also work that way?

Comment: If the Annotation itself is annotated with the Inherited annotation, then the Annotation is inherited on subclasses. The link I sent isn't a duplicate, but it does answer part of your question so you should re-read. Annotations can NOT be inherited from a superclass unless the annotation in use is annotated with the Inherited annotation. If Remove doesn't have the Inherited annotation itself, then no, it's simply not possible. If Remove is your own custom annotation, then add the Inherited to the interface declaration.

Comment: If the method is NOT overwritten then it will be the annotation of the parent class' implementation, which will have the annotation. If the method is overwritten, the only way to have the annotation carry over is as explained above.

Comment: At the time of writing, my question was closed (by some other user) as duplicate of the one you provided. Remove is not my annotation and is not annotated with Inherit. I think I will make a final method that is annotated and which calls a method that is overridable