# Why do JUnit 5 tests not inherit @Test annotation from abstract classes?

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I just realized (while migrating legacy code from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5) that some of our test methods are not executed because they don't have the `@Test` annotation. They don't have it, because they override methods from an abstract superclass (where the annotation is present).

I can easily fix this by adding the `@Test` to each method. But I was wondering if this is intended behavior. It changed from JUnit 4 to 5 but I can't find anything about it in the [official JUnit5 User Guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) or anywhere else.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409338/inherit-annotations-from-abstract-class), Annotations are usually not inherited. But it seems that this was deliberately changed in the new JUnit version. (Or am I missing something?)

### The abstract test class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

abstract class AbstractJUnit5Test {

  @Test
  void generalTest() {
    System.out.println("This is a test in the abstract class");
  }

  @Test
  abstract void concreteTest();
}
```

### The concrete test class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ConcreteJUnt5Test extends AbstractJUnit5Test {

  // only gets executed with an additional @Test annotation:
  @Override
  void concreteTest() { 
    System.out.println("This is from the concrete test method.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an unintentional difference between JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter.

See details at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/960

Edit: after further investigation it seems that this (convenient) behavior from JUnit 4 is actually unintended. See Sam's latest comment at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/960#issuecomment-316114648

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to build some sort of relationship among your test methods. Try if you can use `@Nested`. 
[You can find a sample here](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M1/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested)

Comment: I don't really see how this would help to create a similar setup as with an abstract superclass. At least in my use case, the goal is to have an superclass with common fixture code in `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` methods and abstract methods that have to be implemented by each test-subclass. (so that a lot of similar classes from the same hierarchy can be tested in an uniform way.) Not necessarily good test design, but it worked so far.

Comment: There are only two real possibilities: What's being tested is in fact the same and the base class method should be concrete, or it's not and inheritance is the wrong design here.  Common fixture code could be managed through a JUnit Extension or a number of other options.