# JUnit5 - execute a test method without @Test annotation

Tags: java, junit5

I have a super class that defines `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` methods. The class also has a method that should run only when a system property is set - basically `@EnabledIfSystemPropertyCondition`. Normal tests with `@Test` annotation are in subclasses.

This works well, but the conditional test is shown as skipped in test report - which I want to avoid. Is there any way I can run a test method on a condition but not consider it as a test in normal situations?

This question is not related to inheritance of `@Test` annotations. The basic question is **Is there any way I can run a test method on a condition but not consider it as a test in normal situations?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do JUnit 5 tests not inherit @Test annotation from abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162254/why-do-junit-5-tests-not-inherit-test-annotation-from-abstract-classes)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Had a look at it before I posted this question. It is not same.

Comment: which is why it's useful to add code samples.

Comment: workaraound with `@Test .... { if (myProperty) {doMyTest()}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that you want is to check clause manually inside the test case (just as @Paizo advised in comments). JUnit has several features which allow you skip tests execution such as [Junit-ext](http://code.google.com/p/junit-ext/) project with `@RunIf` annotation or special [Assume clause](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/assumptions-with-assume) which will force test to be skipped if this assumption is not met. But these features also mark test as skipped which is not desired in your case. Another possibility you might think about is modifying your code with the magic of reflection to add/remove annotations at runtime, but this is not possible. Theoretically I can imagine a difficult way using cglib to subclass your test class at runtime and manage annotations just like Spring do, but first of all ask yourself if it worth?

My personal feeling is that you're trying to fix the thing which is working perfectly and not broken. Skipped test in the report is not a failed test. It's cool that you can understand from report was test executed or no.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide any context. Working on a test automation tool plugin for eclipse. The conditional test belongs to the application library and should be invoked only when recording a test. At this time I dynamically create a Java class and run it (No need for cglib - I can use JDT). If I use a standard way of skipping test - each and everyone of the User test cases shows this as a skipped test and is not desirable.