# Spring Boot @Service annotation in extended class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

Hi I have BaseClass and It contains @Service annotation.I want to extend all my class from this class
But In MyExtendedClass @Autowired or other aspect content are not working until I add @Service attribute to my ExtendedClass.Why is this necessary?Is there another method to avoid duplicate attribute?What I want to do is put all my attributes to base class.

```
@Service
public class MyBase {
    public MyBase {
    }
}

//Normally it doesnt have @Service annotation but not work 
public class MyExtendedClass extends MyBase
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inherit annotations from abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409338/inherit-annotations-from-abstract-class)

Answer (score 3):

From [Spring Framework Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) on `@Service` annotation:

The `@Service` is defined as below:

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Service
```

The `@Service` annotation is not marked with the `@Inherited` annotation. This means that this annotation will not be automatically inherited from super classes marked with it to the child classes.