# extending rest controller and model is not working in spring boot applicaion

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I wrote some rest endpoints that are being used to fetch data from the database and we are using them in the frontend to show that data. Later I was thinking to have common code in separate class/classes so I wrote a base controller which has `@RestController` & `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` annotations, and a default `@GetMapping("/")` method to check if the service is working.
Similarly I wrote a base model which has `@Data` annotation from `lombok` and implements `Serializable`.

But when I extend my controllers from `BaseController` endpoints give me `404, not found` error. And my models from `BaseModel` return empty object

Here is my base controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class BaseController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
        return "Deployment successful :)!";
    }
}
```

And base model

```
@Data
public class BaseModel implements Serializable {

}
```

When I used the rest controller annotation without extending from base controller spring automatically detects controllers even if those are in a nested package But extending from base controller show `404`.
Extending from model give empty object as it does not account the `@Data` annotation.

So please let me know how what should I do to make it work by extending from base controller and base model? I don't want to add

- `@RestController` & `@CrossOrigin` annotations on every controller and
- `@Data` annotation & implement `Serializable` on every model.

I also tried to add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.devdoctors.village_automation.stats.controllers")
@EntityScan("com.devdoctors.village_automation.stats.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.devdoctors.village_automation.stats.repos")
```

But the result is the same. `com.devdoctors.village_automation` is the base package where my main class is.

Comment: In which package is BaseController  and BaseModel?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli BaseController is in the same package where other controllers are and BaseModel is in the same package where other models are.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli in the packages listed above in `@ComponentScan` and `@EntityScan`

Comment: What you're trying is not possible. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409338/inherit-annotations-from-abstract-class